# Get DateTime field from table and get year, month, and day on C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server table that has a DateTime field called `ProductionDate`. The format of this field is:  `2015-06-29 00:00:00.000`
I have a C# WinForm application that selects this date with this:

```
string productionDate = String.Empty;
var prodDate = pallets.Select(r => r.Production_Date);
if (prodDate.Count() == 1)
{
    productionDate = prodDate.First().ToString();
}
```

Now, this form calls a second form with this line:
`EditBOL bol = new EditBOL(BOL, Batch, productionDate)`

What I am trying to do is, fill out the second form with the `prodDate` value.
This is what the form looks like:
[image]

I am trying to populate the `Year`, `Month`, and `Day` fields using the `prodDate` argument it gets when the function is called.
This is the function that gets called:

```
public EditBOL(string BOL, string Batch, string prodDate)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtBOL.Text = BOL;
        txtBatch.Text = Batch;
        //Code to breakdown prodDAte variable comes here!!
    }
```

I have tried a lot of different methods. I tried
1. `DateTime.Parse(prodDate, "yyyy-mm-dd", culture)`
2. `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm tt");`
3. `DateTime dateVariable = prodDate??DateTime.MinValue`
The reason I tried all this is, I don't want to use a `substring` on the dateProd variable in the function because, the date can either be `1-1-2015` or `10-10-2015`. The format is NOT `mm-dd-yyyy 00:00:00.000`, it is `m-d-yyyy 00:00:00.000`
So, substring just seems stupid. So I am trying to convert the string to datetime variable and doing `DatetimeVariable.Year`, `DatetimeVariable.Date`, and `DatetimeVariable.Month`.

EDIT 1:Missed a few lines of code on how the date is selected from the table.

Comment: "The format of this field is:  2015-06-29 00:00:00.000" - you said it was a DateTime field, in which case it doesn't have a "format" - when you fetch the value, you should just get a DateTime, not a string...

Comment: `var prodDate` gets this value for that date:
`6-29-2015 00:00:00`

Comment: Well you're calling `ToString()`. I suggest you stop doing that.

Comment: @JonSkeet But the value I am getting from the select statement is a `datetime` variable. I am not able to assign it to a string variable and pass it as an argument. Assigning it to a `DateTime` variable is something I have not been able to successfully accomplish. Check out the accepted answer. That works for me. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Why do you *want* to assign it to a string variable? Why would you want your `EditBOL` constructor to accept a string instead of a `DateTime` parameter? You're basically formatting a `DateTime` and then parsing it again... it's simpler just not to have it as a single string in the first place. (You can then format the day/month/year individually.)

Comment: @JonSkeet You were right. Doing it the way I did it was an issue today in another department when they selected more than one date. Had to do it the way you suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you insist to parse `prodDate`:

```
public EditBOL(string BOL, string Batch, string prodDate)
{
        InitializeComponent();
        txtBOL.Text = BOL;
        txtBatch.Text = Batch;
        //Code to breakdown prodDAte variable comes here!!
        string[] tokens = prodDate.Split(' ')[0].Split('-');
        yearTextBox.Text = tokens[0];
        monthTextBox.Text = tokens[1];
        dayTextBox.Text = tokens[2];
}
```

I would prefer this approach:

```
public EditBOL(string BOL, string Batch, string prodDate)
{
        InitializeComponent();
        txtBOL.Text = BOL;
        txtBatch.Text = Batch;
        //Code to breakdown prodDAte variable comes here!!
        DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(prodDate);
        yearTextBox.Text = date.Year.ToString();
        monthTextBox.Text = date.Month.ToString();
        dayTextBox.Text = date.Day.ToString();
}
```

Comment: It says `Index was outside the bounds of the array`. If I understood what this code does, I would fix it. Could you help?

Comment: I used the your example as input `2015-06-29 00:00:00.000`  and got the right results. Which input (`prodDate`) are you testing?

Comment: Check the question again, I edited the code that is used to get the production date value from the database. I apologize.

Comment: I tested it again, it should work with both approaches.

Comment: A better still approach would be to accept the value as a `DateTime` instead of converting it from a `DateTime` *to* a `string` and then parsing the `string` back to a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `DateTime.ParseExact()`:

```
public EditBOL(string BOL, string Batch, string prodDate)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    txtBOL.Text = BOL;
    txtBatch.Text = Batch;

    string format = "yyyy-M-d h:m:s.fff";
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(prodDate, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    textBoxYear.Test = dt.Year.ToString();
    textBoxMonth.Test = dt.Month.ToString();
    textBoxDay.Test = dt.Day.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, I tried that too. But, I did not try storing the format in a separate variable and using that in ParseExact. Will give that a shot now. Thank you

Comment: @CrazyCucumber, I've edited `format` variable, see edited answer.